# Flutter: How to disable Elevated button "onPressed:" and keep it disabled

Tags: flutter

I'd like to disable 2 button when one of them has been pressed. When app is restarted they should still be disabled. How can I do that?
Having the buttons no appear would also be great but not a must.

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment:
      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            positiveIncrement(hospitalName);
          },
          child: Text("Yes",
            style:
              GoogleFonts.lexendMega(),),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colour("#87D68D"),
            ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                negativeIncrement(hospitalName);
              },
              child: Text(
                "No",
                style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(),
              ),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colour("#E3655B"),
                  ),
                 ),
        ],
       ),
```

Comment: Use packages like local storage or shared_preferences to store the current status of the button. Read value and handle  visibility of the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make a bool method and use turnery operator for this purpose

```
       bool isEnabled=false;
       onPressed: isEnabled ?() {
       // do something
                     }: null,
```

Comment: if it helpful kindly upvote also.